# Error while trying to create dynamic html elements with php using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, runtime-error

When I try to create dynamically some boxes in HTML with PHP I get the following error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $sql = 'call getservers()';
    $retval = mysqli_query( $conn,$sql );
    if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not get data.');
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval)) {
    $server_array = $row['result'];
    }
    foreach($server_array as $value) {
    echo <<<HEREDOC
            <div class="card card-custom">
                                            <div class="card-header">
                                                <div class="card-title">
                                                    <span class="card-icon">
                                                        <i class="fas fa-server text-primary text-primary"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <h3 class="card-label">Server 1 
                                                    <small>192.168.1.1</small></h3>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card-toolbar">
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-light-danger mr-2">
                                                        <i class="flaticon2-drop"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-light-success mr-2">
                                                        <i class="flaticon2-gear"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-light-primary">
                                                        <i class="flaticon2-bell-2"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-body">No Description Given.</div>
                                        </div>
HEREDOC;
    }
?>
```

(The MySql query returns the JSON Array correctly)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `$server_array` is defined as a string, which you then overwrite on each iteration of the `while`-loop, so at the end, it will just contain the last record (which most likely isn't an array). However, a better solution would probably be to remove the `foreach` completely and put the HTML inside the `while`-loop directly, instead of having two loops that contains the same data.

Comment: replace echo <<<HEREDOC with echo <<<'EOD'.

Comment: @HassanALi - What would that change/solve?

Comment: please try it then let me know.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The MySQL query returns the JSONArray with all the records from the table. The result is just 1 line, which contains the JSONArray in it. Here is a result with example data:

[{"server_name": "Test Server 1", "server_ip": "192.168.1.2", "server_hostname": "testserver1.example.com"},{"server_name": "Test Server 2", "server_ip": "192.169.1.105", "server_hostname": "testserver2.example.com"}]

Comment: Perhaps you meant: `$server_array = array(); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval)) {$server_array[] = $row['result'];}`

Comment: What have you tried to check **where** this problem occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `json_decode($server_array, true)` to get an associative array you can cycle through.

i.e.

```
<?php
$server_array = '[{"server_name": "Test Server 1", "server_ip": "192.168.1.2", "server_hostname": "testserver1.example.com"},{"server_name": "Test Server 2", "server_ip": "192.169.1.105", "server_hostname": "testserver2.example.com"}]';
$server_array = json_decode($server_array, true);

foreach($server_array as $value) {
    foreach($value as $item) {
        echo <<<HEREDOC
            $item;
HEREDOC;
    }
}
```

Output
`Test Server 1; 192.168.1.2; testserver1.example.com; Test Server 2; 192.169.1.105; testserver2.example.com;`

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/fkTr3)